# Customised search in a text file

Tags: batch-file

I have a text file with content :

```
process.exe Pid:4513
G:\data\Windows
process.exe Pid:6754
G:\data\Linux
process.exe Pid:4328
G:\data\MacOS
```

I want a batch script which :

```
Searches for 1st occurrence of 'process.exe' and then searches for 1st occurrence of any one of the 'Windows/Linux/MacOS' word and let's assume Windows word found then send the following output to a text file 'Output.txt' :
process.exe  Pid:4513  Windows

Then searches for 2nd occurrence of 'process.exe' and then searches again for 1st occurrence of any one of the 'Windows/Linux/MacOS' word and let's assume Linux word found then send the following output to the same text file 'Output.txt' :
process.exe  Pid:6754  Linux

and so on..
```

finally, 'Output.txt' file should have following contents :

```
process.exe  Pid:4513  Windows
process.exe  Pid:6754  Linux
process.exe  Pid:4328  MacOS
```

Comment: And your programming question is... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this question isn't strictly within the rules since you've shown no attempt to solve the problem yourself and this isn't a write-some-code-for-me-for-free site; I believe that someone searching for a solution to a similar problem may appreciate an answer:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "keystring1="
(
 FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  q19366050.txt
  ) DO (
  ECHO %%a|FIND "HsvDataSource.exe" >NUL
  IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 SET keystring1=%%a
  FOR %%b IN (USHFMPROD GSPROD TLPROD) DO (
   ECHO %%a|FIND "%%b" >NUL
   IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 IF DEFINED keystring1 CALL ECHO(%%keystring1%% %%b&SET "keystring1="
  )
 )
)>newfile.txt
TYPE newfile.txt
GOTO :EOF
```

The data should be in q19366050.txt and the report is produced in newfile.txt. Tweak to suit yourself.

---

Revised for speed 20131028T0725Z

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "keystring1="
(
 FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  q19366050.txt
  ) DO (
  ECHO %%a|FIND "HsvDataSource.exe" >NUL
  IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
   IF DEFINED keystring1 (
    FOR %%b IN (USHFMPROD GSPROD TLPROD) DO IF DEFINED keystring1 (
     ECHO %%a|FIND "%%b" >NUL
     IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 CALL ECHO(%%keystring1%% %%b&SET "keystring1="
    )
   )
  ) ELSE (SET keystring1=%%a)
 )
)>newfile.txt
TYPE newfile.txt
GOTO :EOF
```

What may seem odd here is the multiple use of `IF DEFINED keystring1`.

The first instance ensures that the inner `FOR` is only executed once the executable is found.

The next instance ensures that the time-costly piped-echo is NOT executed for the remaining target strings once `%%b` has been found.

There would be a marginal further improvement if the target strings were listed in order of frequency, so if the strings occur 60%/30%/10% of the time, then 60% of the time only 1 `ECHO` would be executed; 2 `ECHO`s 30% and 3 `ECHO`s 10%.

Actual runtime on sample data (and I've no recollection of where I got that...) was 80sec with the original and 34 sec with this version; running with a 99K sourcetext.

Comment: Hi Peter..being a new user to both batch-scripting and as well as to this site, honestly speaking i was not aware about the rules..but i would definitely take care of this from now onwards..thanks for your response...I have tried your code but its throwing following error: Pls see attached 'Error Message'image.

Comment: You have discovered how to operate from the command prompt. The idea of batch files is to have a text file containing the batch instructions. That way, you can easily edit it and don't have to type it repeatedly. Cut-and-Paste the batch file to a file named `whateveryoulike.bat` Notepad is adequate - barely - but be careful as it can try to format the text and batch is quite sensitive to syntax. I use EDITPLUS. The file needs to be saved on the `PATH` (if you enter `PATH` at the prompt, you'll get a semicolon-separated list of directories. You can adjust path using `PATH EDITOR`

Comment: Then you can execute the batch file by simply entering `whateveryoulike` at the prompt. There's a small quirk though - in a batch file, a metavariable (loop-control variable) is nominated as `%%x` whereas from the prompt, it is `%x`. EDITPLUS and PATH EDITOR - Google is your friend... Batchers often set up a special directory for batch files. `C:\BATCH` and `C:\belfry` are popular. Just need to add that directory to your PATH.

Comment: Many Thanks Peter..!! EDITPLUS and PATH EDITOR really made it run smoothly...and i must say what a healthy start in Batch-script for me..I'll continue learning !! Thanks..:)

Comment: @Magoo..why this script is taking little more time to provide output..? :)

Comment: No idea - the script hasn't changed. What has changed? Is the output correct (even if it is slow?) What degree of slowing happens? 10% or 10 times? Has the input file changed size?

Comment: Input file would have maxsize of 150 KB and Output is also coming correct everytime..but its taking around 30 sec to provide output for a input file size of 85 KB.Isn't it little long ?